# Windows Updates installation fails - has never happened before

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-update

I am running W2K3, have Windows auto update enabled and things have been running smoothly for a long time, but the last time I have OK'ed to install downloaded updates all of them have failed.

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the WindowsUpdate.log in your Windows directory. That will tell you exactly what is going on and should provide some more info on where to look next e.g. errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check event viewer for any details on the errors.  Windows Update itself may provide some failure codes that you can look up.  Additionally, try installing them one at a time to see if just one of the installs is causing the whole set to fail. Narrowing it down to a smaller area  will help you determine the cause.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error code? To see error code go to Windows Update website and try to update from there, once it fails click on the error details, you should be able to see the error code.

Then check my answer for this question to see if it is related.

[Error 0x80070005 when installing updates from Microsoft Update](https://serverfault.com/questions/70315/error-0x80070005-when-installing-updates-from-microsoft-update/172586#172586)